The length between orthocenter and intersection point of two circles

Here the construction of the diagram.

Draw a circle $C_1$ as incircle of triangle $ABC$. $I$ is the incenter and H is orthocenter of triangle $ABC$.
Draw circle $C_2$ as circumcircle of triangle $BIC$. Here $C_2$ intersects $AC$ at $D$ and extension of $AB$ at $E$.
Draw circle $C_3$ as circumcircle of triangle $ADE$.
Draw circle $C_4$ as circumcircle of triangle $ABC$. Circle $C_3$ and circle $C_4$ intersect each other at $P$.

Given that $AB=10, AC=16$ and $CE=16$ what is the length of $HP$?
First of all, I apologize if my diagram drawn badly. I spent hours to draw and redraw to give better perspective. Whenever I draw I always obtain $C_4$ and $C_3$ pretty much same in size. It made me wonder if the size would be the same  in every condition. But I cannot figure out how to prove that claim. If it is proven,  $A,I$ and $P$ must be collinear right?
Secondly, I have initiative to make circumcenter of triangle $ABC$ and label it as $J$ considering that $H,I$ and $J$ must be colinear and maybe I could make use property of orthocenter and incircle namely $IJ=2HI$. So here I draw triangle $HJP$ hoping it would help to solve the problem. I also have a claim that triangle $HJP$ somehow similar to triangle $ABC$. But again, I cannot prove my claim.
I also found that triangle $ABC$ cannot be right-angled triangle since it make $CE$ can never be 16. (I tried choose special case to make it easier in calculation since there is no restriction about the type of the triangle).
I cannot figure out any further ideas. I very appreciate for every responses, ideas and answer you share. Thankyou in advance.

A triangle's incenter, orthocenter, and circumcenter are not necessarily collinear. However, the centroid, orthocenter, and circumcenter lie on the Euler line.

Oh, really? Is not centroid and Incenter supposed to be the exactly same point in every triangle?@Blue

I had done my research, and yes you are correct, centroid isn’t necessary the same point with Incenter. Thanks for let me know. @Blue

"Is not centroid and Incenter supposed to be the exactly same point in every triangle?" They're distinct, except in equilateral triangles. FYI: The incenter is $X(1)$ in the Encyclopedia of Triangle Centers; the centroid is $X(2)$. (The circumcenter and orthocenter are $X(3)$ and $X(4)$.)

Let's show, first of all, that triangle $ACE$ is equilateral.
As $AC=CE$ we also have $\angle CAE=\angle CEA=\alpha$.
On the other hand:
$$
\angle CIB=180°-{\angle ACB\over2}-{\angle CBA\over2}=90°+{\alpha\over2}.
$$
But $\angle CIB$ and $\angle BEC$ both insist on the same chord $CB$ of circle $BIC$, on opposite arcs. Hence $\angle CIB = 180°-\angle BEC$, that is:
$$
90°+{\alpha\over2}=180°-\alpha,
\quad\text{which gives:}\quad
\alpha=60°.
$$
It follows that $ACE$ is equilateral, as it was to be proved.
Note that, by symmetry, $AD=AB=10$.
Moreover, orthocenter $H$ also lies on circle $BIC$, because
(see figure below):
$$
\angle CHB=\angle GHF=180°-\alpha=120°.
$$
Circle $ADE$ is congruent to circle $BIC$. To see why, reflect triangle $AEC$ about $EC$ and let $J$, $K$ the intersections of the reflected triangle with circle $BIC$. It is not difficult to prove that $BC=CK=KB$ (all these chords are subtended by $120°$ inscribed angles) and thus $CJ=BD=AD$. It follows that trapezoid $ADLE$ is the same as trapezoid $CJKE$, rotated by $60°$ about point $E$.
Circle $ADE$ is then the image of circle $BIC$ under a rotation of $60°$ about point $E$. This implies that the center of circle $BIC$ lies on circle $ADE$. Analogously, circle $ABC$ is the reflection of circle $ADE$ about line $AI$ (the bisector of $\angle EAC$), hence the center of circle $BIC$ also lies on circle $ABC$, and is thus point $P$.
$PH$ is then the radius of circle $BIC$. To compute it, we can find $DE=14$ by the cosine rule applied to triangle $ADE$ and then:
$$
PH={DE\over2\sin\alpha}={14\over\sqrt3}.
$$


What a well explained answer. Thank you very much


Particular case, where triangle ABE is equilateral. In this case as can be seen in figure circle $C_2$ passes vertexes A and C and the orthocenter of triangle ABC and its radius is equal to that of circumcircle of triangle ABC and $PH=R$. So we have to find R.We have:
$\angle ABC=60^o$
$\angle ACE_1=30^o$
therefore:
$AE_1=\frac{16}2=8\Rightarrow BE_1=10-8=2$
$CE_1=\frac{\sqrt3}2\times 16=8\sqrt 3$
$CB=\sqrt{(8\sqrt 3)^2+2^2}=14$
Area of triangle ABC is:
$S=\frac{(CE_1=8\sqrt 3)\times 10}2=40\sqrt 3$
Finally R is:
$R=\frac{abc}{4s}=\frac{16\times 14\times 10}{4\times 40\sqrt 3}=\frac{14\sqrt 3}3$

I should have known to work on equilateral triangle for  the particular case rather than right-angled triangle. Anyway thankyou for the answer. @sirous

In addition, a very good diagram you attach really made a very clear understanding about the problem. But, I wonder is there a mathematical reason why in this case PH must be equal to R, except only deduced from the diagram? @sirous
